# How to getelementbyid using ajax.response

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, dom, getelementbyid

I use  php to sent back div name to ajax call using post 
I want to  use the js variable that I get using ajax and then  use this to dom a div:

```
idisis=ajax.responseText;
document.getElementById(idisis).innerHTML= some text; 
// ('idisis') || (''+idisis+'')|| ("'+idisis+'")
```

But it doesn't work; it is possible ?

Comment: what do you mean by "it don't work". what exactly is going wrong? what is ajax in this case? Im guessing you're not doing this in the callback of the ajax call as you should be. also "some text" should have quotes

Comment: `ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
              if (ajax.responseText) {
              
             idisis=ajax.responseText;     
                
        document.getElementById(idisis).innerHTML= "some text";        

             }
       }
        }`it don't work nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a raw XMLHttpRequest post function I made, and a few other goodies. It's backward compatible.

```
function phpEncode(obj){
  var r = [];
  if(obj instanceof Array){
    for(var i=0,l=obj.length; i<l; i++){
      r.push(phpEncode(obj[i]));
    }
    return '%5B'+r.join(',')+'%5D';
  }
  else if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj){
    for(var i in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        var v = obj[i], s;
        if(typeof v === 'object' && v){
          s = encodeURIComponent('"'+i.replace('"', '\\"')+'":')+phpEncode(v);
        }
        else{
          v = typeof v === 'string' ? '"'+v.replace('"', '\"')+'"' : v;
          s = encodeURIComponent('"'+i.replace('"', '\\"')+'":'+v);
        }
        r.push(s);
      }
    }
    return '%7B'+r.join(',')+'%7D';
  }
  else{
    r = typeof obj === 'string' ? '"'+obj.replace('"', '\\"')+'"' : obj;
    return ''+r;
  }
}
function phpAccept(respText){
  return eval('('+decodeURIComponent(respText)+')');
}
function clone(obj){
  return phpAccept(phpEncode(obj));
}
function post(send, where, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('POST', where); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
      if(success)success.call(c, phpAccept(x.responseText));
    }
  }
  if(send && typeof send === 'object' && !(send instanceof Array)){
    var r = [];
    for(var p in send){
      r.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+'='+phpEncode(send[p]));
    }
    if(r.length)x.send(r.join('&'));
  }
  return x;
}
post({testProperty:'testValue'}, 'yourPage.php', function(response){
  // evaluate response and run all your other code here
});
```